# using java to call python in eclipse path issue

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I was struggling with the following:

when i use the path of python program in the normal desktop, java can run the python program in eclipse.
However, i use the path of python program which is in the tomcat, java cannot run the python program in eclipse.

```
// String callPyPath="C:\\Python27\\python C:\\Users\\Desktop\\myprogram.py"+" ";
```

// GOOOOD it work!!!

```
String callPyPath="C:\\Python27\\python C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 8.0\\webapps\\testWeb\\WEB-INF\\classes\\com\\myprogram.py"+" ";
```

// BAD it cannot work!!!

```
   String addKeyWord1=KeyWord1+" ";
   String addsourcePath=sourcePath+" ";
   String addKeyWord2=KeyWord2+" ";
   String saveresultPath="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\results\\";
   String cmd = callPyPath+addKeyWord1+addsourcePath+addKeyWord2+saveresultPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the space in your path.

```
String callPyPath="C:\\Python27\\python C:\\Program\ Files\\Apache\ Software\ Foundation\\Tomcat\ 8.0\\webapps\\testWeb\\WEB-INF\\classes\\com\\myprogram.py"+" "
```

Or replace the spaces after the creation of the `String`:

```
String callPyPath="C:\\Python27\\python C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 8.0\\webapps\\testWeb\\WEB-INF\\classes\\com\\myprogram.py"+" "
callPyPath.replace(" ", "\\ ");
```

Comment: then simply replace the space in the String by escaped space : see edited answer.

Comment: I do not think it works. C:\\Python27\\python-space-C:\\P ..... the-space- should not be replace